# asyncio Queue put with delay

Tags: python, queue, delay, coroutine

I'm using [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/index.html) and am trying to figure out the correct way to "call_later" for coroutines. Specifically, I'm trying to use the [asyncio.Queue.put](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.put) (which is a coroutine) with [asyncio.BaseEventLoop.call_later](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=asyncio.baseeventloop#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.call_later). This doesn't work because call_later only allows callbacks and not coroutines. I haven't been able to find a builtin function to behave like call_later for coroutines. This is what I ended up doing to solve my problem but it doesn't seem very eloquent. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def func(self):
    data = self.queue.get()
    try:
        #do some stuff
    except Exception as e:
        logger.warn(e)

        @asyncio.coroutine
        def queue_put_delay(data):
            yield from asyncio.sleep(self.retry_delay)
            yield from self.queue.put(data)

        asyncio.async(queue_put_delay(data), loop=self.loop)
    finally:
        #do some stuff
        asyncio.async(func(), loop=self.loop)
```